# Bash script fail to detect disk

Tags: bash, scripting, mount, mkfs

I got a script that is supposed to reformat and mount `/dev/disk/by-label/backup_disk` into `/mnt/backup_disk`. Like this:

```
/sbin/mkfs.ext4 -q -L backup_disk /dev/disk/by-label/backup_disk
mount -t ext4 /dev/disk/by-label/backup_disk /mnt/backup_disk -o noatime,data=writeback
```

Bash output is:

```
mount: special device /dev/disk/by-label/backup_disk does not exist
```

But right after execution, if I type on terminal:

```
mount /dev/disk/by-label/backup_disk /mnt/backup_disk/
```

Mount is fine without any kind of error.

What is causing the error when using the script?

EDIT: Solved adding a few seconds sleep like suggested in comments.

Comment: Have you tried putting a `sleep 10` or so before the `mount` in your script?

Comment: @Anthon that actually solved problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably do some sort of delay loop (with a maximum iterations) that sleeps for 1 second, then checks whether the directory `/dev/disk/by-label/backup_disk` now exists.  The following should work, but you may need to debug it.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o errexit
set -o unset

$DIRECTORY=/dev/disk/by-label/backup_disk
# do your reformat here
until [ -d "$DIRECTORY" ]; do 
  sleep 1 
done
# now continue with the mount and other operations...
```

I like to write [defensive bash scripts](http://ben.goodacre.name/tech/Writing_defensive_Bash_scripts#Exit_on_error).  That's what the two "set -o" statements are for.

You can also add a counter to keep track of how many times you go through the loop and then break out after 30/60/90 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You should give the OS a few seconds to actually detect that the newly formatted partition is available. Start with a

```
sleep 10
```

before the line with `mount ..` (and maybe reduce that if you don't want to wait that long while running the script).